# Fill blank variable with subsequent values

Tags: spss

I have a dataset structured like below;

```
id    contracthours13    contracthours14    contracthours13u    contracthours14u
12    .                  13                 .                   13
13    30                 30                 .                   .
14    .                  .                  15                  16
15    .                  5                  6                   7
```

If `contracthours13` is missing I want the value in `contracthours14` to move across. If this is missing then I want `contacthours13u` to move across and the same then for `contracthours14u` if the previous 3 are all missing. I know this is fairly simple syntax but I just can't get my head around how to do it without having the run simpler syntax 3 times. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: below is what I would like my dataset to look like afterwards.

```
id    contracthours13
12    13
13    30
14    15
15    5
```

Comment: Can you have valid response to multiple variables? Or can only a single variable be populated? Please define "move across" more clearly. Do all prior variables before the first valid variable need to be filled? Does the original variable remained preserved or is it then replaced with missing if "moved across"?

Comment: I'll edit the question to give a better idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Essentially if `contracthours13` is blank I want it filled with the first of the other 3 variables (looking from left to right) that has a non-missing value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [VECTOR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_vector_examples.htm) / [LOOP](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_loop_indexing_clause.htm) examples.

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID CH13 CH14 CH13U CH14U.
BEGIN DATA.
1 -1 13 -1 -1
2 30 30 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 15 16
4 -1 5 6 7
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DSRaw.
RECODE ALL (-1=SYSMIS).

VECTOR V= CH14 TO CH14U.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 3 IF (NVALID(CH13)=0).
  COMPUTE CH13=V(#i).
END LOOP IF NVALID(V(#i))=1.
LIST.
EXE.

**List**
  ID     CH13     CH14    CH13U    CH14U 

1.00    13.00    13.00      .        . 
2.00    30.00    30.00      .        . 
3.00    15.00      .      15.00    16.00 
4.00     5.00     5.00     6.00     7.00 


Number of cases read:  4    Number of cases listed:  4
```